# jqgrid Hide Grouping column - Alignment Problem IE browser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Hai,
i faced alignment problem in IE browser .
Scenario:
1. make group column as hidden ( groupColumnShow : [false])
2. make any column hidden, (hidden:true) 
Screen shot attached.[image]

[Screenshot] http://uatdemo.sify.net:4080/jqgrid.png

Please help to resolve.

```
jQuery("#list48").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 30,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date",
             formatter:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, editable:true},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float",
             formatter:"number", editable:true},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float",
             editable:true},        
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    pager: "#plist48",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'name',
    grouping:true,
    groupingView : {
        groupField : ['name'],
        groupColumnShow : [false]
    },
    caption: "Hide Grouping Column"
});
```

Comment: Please setup a http://jsFiddle.net with test data (HTML), the CSS you are using, and scripts

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem which you describes. You can compare your code with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithGrouping.htm) and try to find your error.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. The solution I found is as following:

1. Put all hidden fields at the end (in colModel)
2. Define this function:

   ```
   function resolveAlignmentJqgridBug() {  
     /*  
     Without the below line, the "jqgfirstrow" has child <TD> for every hidden column.  
     These <TD>s have non zero width and with "display: none".  
     Setting the style of these <TD>s to "width: '0px', display: 'block'" resolves the problem. */
     jQuery(".jqgfirstrow").find(":hidden").css({width: '0px', display: 'block'});  
   }
   ```
3. Call this function after the grid definition and every time when I change the grouping (I have dynamic grouping changing):

   ```
   jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
   ...
   datatype: "json",  
       colNames:['not hidden field','hidden field'],  
       colModel:[  
       ...  
       {name:'typeId', hidden:false},  
           {name:'url', hidden:true}  
       ],  
       autowidth: true,   
       shrinkToFit:true,  
   ...  
   grouping: true,  
       groupingView : {  
       groupField : ['statusDesc'],  
       groupColumnShow : [true],  
       groupText : ['<b>{0}</b> ({1})'],  
       groupCollapse : false,  
       groupOrder: ['asc'],  
       groupSummary : [false],  
       groupDataSorted : false   
        },  
   ...  
   });  

   resolveAlignmentJqgridBug();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This bug can be solved by adding the directive in top of HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on this a little bit as your advice seems to be some kind of odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
jQuery("#list48").jqGrid('hideCol', "yourColumnName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Call on Load Complete Of JQGrid event at the end

```
loadComplete: function () {
  jQuery(".jqgfirstrow").find(":hidden").css("cssText", "width:0px!important;height:0px!important;display:none!important");        
}
```